# Using Sessions to add items to a cart

Tags: php, html

I have been following a tutorial for a php shopping cart,

I have checked my code over and I am to the point where the add to cart button SHOULD be adding the products into the sidebar.

However, it appears to skip over my if statement and go straight to the else error message stating the product ID is invalid.
I have checked that the SKU in the database match thought that are displayed in $id so i'm a little lost as to why this error persists?

PHP for Products:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == "add") {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    if (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id])) {
        $_SESSION['cart'][$id]['quantity']++;
    } else {
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE SKU=$id";
        $query2 = mysql_query($sql2);

        if(mysql_num_rows($query2) != 0){
            $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2);
            $_SESSION['cart'][$row2['SKU']] = array("quantity" => 1, "price" =>      $row2['price']);

        } else {
            $message = "This product ID is invalid";
        }
    }
}

?>

<h2 class="message"><?php if(isset($message)){echo $message;} ?></h2>
<h1>Product Page</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>

<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY SKU ASC";
$query = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
?>

  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['description']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo "&pound;" . $row['price']; ?></td>
    <td><a href="index.php?page=products&action=add&id=<?php echo $row['SKU']; ?>">Add to cart</a></td>
  </tr>

<?php
}
?>
```

PHP for Index.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    require_once("connect.php");
    if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
        $pages = array("products","cart");
        if (in_array($_GET['page'],$pages)) {
            $page = $_GET['page'];
        } else {
            $page = "products";
        }
    } else {
        $page = "products";
    }

?>

    <html>
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <title>Shopping Cart - WebThatWorks Ltd</title>
      </head>

      <body>
        <div id="container">
        <div id="main"><?php require($page. ".php"); ?></div>
        <div id="sidebar">

        <h1>Cart</h1>
<?php
          if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
              $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE SKU IN (";
              foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value) {
                  $sql .=$id. ",";
              }
              $sql = substr($sql,0,-1) . ")ORDER BY SKU ASC";
              $query = mysql_query($sql);
              while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
?>
                <p><?php echo $row['name']; ?><?php echo $_SESSION['cart'][$row['SKU']]['quantity']; ?></p>
                <a href="index.php?page=cart">Go To Cart</a>
<?php
              }
          } else {
              echo "<p>Your Cart Is Empty.  <br /> Please Add some products</a>";
          }
?>
```

If you require me to post the structure of my database, I shall do so

Comment: As a side note: `mysql_*` methods will be deprecated in the near future so you should consider making yourself familiar with [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) (they're a real treat btw)

Comment: Please start properly indenting your code.

Comment: Where and how do you establish a connection to the database? Is this working correctly?

Comment: var_dump the query immediately before you execute it to check that the query is what you think it is. I've tripped up many times with this!

Comment: I know there should be indents to the code, however the editor on my server doesn't seem to allow tabbing indents

Comment: The database connection is established through another page connect.php, this is working correctly otherwise the products wouldn't even display

Comment: I have just tried var_dump($row2) and var_dump($query2) separately instead of the else message, however nothing is displayed from the dump, at all

Comment: @WibblyWobbly can you show what `var_dump($id)` contains?

Comment: Have just ran var_dump($id) on the index.php page at the very end, it displayed NULL -.-

Comment: Do it on the product page, before the IF that doesn't work.

Comment: Have tried it before both IF statements, it caused the page to fail to load (unfortunately I dont know how to enable PHP error reporting)

Comment: in your php for products, after the session_start please put this code `echo "This page is:".$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];` and tell us exactly what it says

Comment: @WibblyWobbly can you give us an example of an SKU that isn't working?

Comment: @Sharky This page is:/phpDiscount(2)/index.php?page=products&action=add&id=test1

Comment: @MrCode I wish i could, all of the products display that error when I click add to cart, which means the issue is somewhere between matching the $id to the SKU stored in the db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your SKU is a string and so it needs quotes in the query:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE SKU='" . mysql_real_escape_string($id) . "'";
```

I also added the escape call to prevent SQL Injection, but for best security and other benefits, you should switch to a modern API such as PDO or MySQLi and use prepared statements.

You will also need to make sure the quotes are added to the IN query as well.

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value) {
    $sql .="'" . mysql_real_escape_string($id) . "',";
}
```

Comment: Have just included this within my code and it doesn't display any products at all now :

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you SO much!
I did think that using strings as SKU's would be problematic, in future I think i'll just stick to int values.
Once again, thankyou!